# Expanding a Qt Layout : how to put a widget on the right side and the let the other widget to fully fill the left?

Tags: qt, layout, qt4

I want to put a widget on the right side of a QHBoxLayout, and the other spaces should expand the left side. I've set the widget's SizePolicy to Expanding, but it's not valid. Anyone could offer some help? Thanks.

Code is here:

```
QHBoxLayout* tmplayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
tmplayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
lineEdit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
tmplayout->addWidget(lineEdit, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
tmplayout->addWidget(pushButton, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
```

lineEdit should expand.

Comment: Please post the code you're having problems with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing:

```
tmplayout->addWidget(lineEdit, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
tmplayout->addWidget(pushButton, 0, Qt::AlignRight);
```

To:

```
tmplayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
tmplayout->addWidget(pushButton);
```

When dealing with simple layouts like this, there is no need to specify alignments or stretch factors explicitly.

If you want to force pushButton to specific size, you can use [setMinimumSize](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop), [setMaximumSize](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#maximumSize-prop), and [setFixedSize](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-2)

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

For the widgets you want to be on the left and expand, try to simply add them before the ones on the right, and add a `1` for their stretch factor. For example,

```
tmplayout->addWidget(exampleWidget, 1);
```

Then, you could simply add the widgets you want to be on the right side after the ones on the left, using just:

```
tmplayout->addWidget(lineEdit);
tmplayout->addWidget(pushbutton);
```

This will automatically give them a stretch factor of 0.

Since the stretch factor of `exampleWidget` in this example is `1` which is higher than the default `0`, `exampleWidget` will expand; and, since you add it before the others, it will be on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but maybe you need to look into [QSpacerItem](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qspaceritem.html). If that is not helpful, maybe you can make a rough mock-up in Qt-Creator and post the screen shots (one example showing approx. what you have, one example showing what you want)

Comment: I mean, how could I let the lineEdit fullfill the left part of the layout. Do you understand now?

Comment: I think ExplodingRat has the answer for you, either leave the values for strech and alignment out or set them useful values. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qboxlayout.html#addWidget

Answer (score 0):

Try `fixed` or `minimum` size policies. Even you may want to fix the maximum width.